# SQL Select Statement LIKE IN

Tags: sql

I need to write a select statement which returns a list of users where a list of SenderSubIDs exist in a field called constraint_values:

I need a LIKE IN statement ideally:

```
SELECT SenderSubID FROM fix_user_subids WHERE SenderSubID IN ('**00390529MGERAN1**','**00912220PBALDIS**','**03994113LDAMBRO**','**04004308SLOMBAR**','**04935278CARELLI**','**4004308SLOMBARD**')

SELECT * FROM fix_dyno_rule_defs WHERE constraint_values LIKE '%**00390529MGERAN1**%'
```

Returns:

`rule_def_id   tag msg_type    required    constraint_values   constraint_type data_type   default_value   validation_type trans_type  attribute_tag   trans_tag   memo
99800   10000   D,F,G   0   ((50,4,1,00390529MGERAN1)or(50,4,1,00912220PBALDIS)or(50,4,1,03994113LDAMBRO)or(50,4,1,04004308SLOMBAR)or(50,4,1,04935278CARELLI)or(50,4,1,4004308SLOMBARD))and(21,4,1,3)#STROP1#addattr(EQD,EQST)  0   1   #TAG=6506#  12  1800    0   0   Set EQD=1 for Equity Desk`

I wrote this:

```
SELECT * FROM fix_dyno_rule_defs WHERE constraint_values LIKE '%' + (SELECT MAX(SenderSubID) FROM fix_user_subids WHERE SenderSubID IN ('00390529MGERAN1','00912220PBALDIS','03994113LDAMBRO','04004308SLOMBAR','04935278CARELLI','4004308SLOMBARD')) +'%'
```

But need it without the MAX as there is a list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get your ideal.  Use `or`:

```
SELECT SenderSubID
FROM fix_user_subid
WHERE SenderSubID like '%00390529MGERAN1%' OR
      SenderSubID like '%00912220PBALDIS%' OR
      SenderSubID like '%04004308SLOMBAR%' OR
      SenderSubID like '%04935278CARELLI%' OR
      SenderSubID like '%4004308SLOMBARD%'
```

Comment: It could also be hacked together as a regexp with `(val|val|val|val)` but that's more complicated and less readable, probably slower.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski . . . Assuming the OP is using a database that has regular expression support.  If so, that is a good idea.

Comment: Indeed - when I posted that, I had thought I saw a `mysql` tag, but in my defense I was making my kids' breakfast at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right (and I might not be!) you're looking to get results from the table fix_dyno_rule_defs.

In which case, can't you just do a simple join?

ie:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fdrd.*
FROM  fix_dyno_rule_defs fdrd 
JOIN  fix_user_subid fus 
      ON fdrd.constraint_values LIKE '%' + REPLACE(fus.SenderSubID, '*','') + '%'
WHERE fus.SenderSubID IN ('**00390529MGERAN1**','**00912220PBALDIS**',
                          '**03994113LDAMBRO**','**04004308SLOMBAR**',
                          '**04935278CARELLI**','**4004308SLOMBARD**')
```

Comment: Hi James,
This returns no results.
If i take out your where clause and just run:

SELECT fdrd.*
FROM  fix_dyno_rule_defs fdrd 
JOIN  fix_user_subids fus ON fdrd.constraint_values LIKE '%' + '4004308SLOMBARD' + '%'
It returns results, so think there might be something wrong with the where?

Comment: @Jaron787 actually yes - I missed it before, but using your data theres no `**` surrounding the ids in the table fix_dyno_rule_defs, but there is in fix_user_subids. I've edited my answer to include a  `REPLACE` to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

/*This should help you try this
declare a temp table and store all the IDs in it*/

```
declare @tempSenderIDs Table(
    T_TableID varchar(10)
)

insert into @tempSender
(
    T_TableID
)
values
select 
    senderSubID
from
    SenderSubIDs
```

/*final result will come from here*/

```
select
    f.SenderSubIDs
from 
    fix_user_subid f
where 
    s.ConstraintValue like '%' + (select T_TableID from @tempSenderIDs) +'%'
```